# Set PHP Variables from values returned in DB

Tags: php, arrays

Newbie to PHP and trying to learn it.  I have returned data from my DB.

So the rows may look something like below

```
ID--------Name--------PhoneNo
1         Joe         1234
2         Jane        5678
3         Tom         0000
```

I am using the msql_fetch_array to return the data as below:

```
    <?php
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $NameOne = $row['Name'];
            }
    ?>
```

This is placing the name 'Joe' in the variable name NameOne as expected.  What is the best way however to get Jane and Tome into variables called $NameTwo and $NameThree that I can then echo these variables further down in my html and similary I want to place the phone number retrieved into seperate variables and refer to them later in my html.

Comment: You shouldn't want that. What if you'll have 10.000+ records? And what if 10.000.000+ ? Use arrays instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ideal approch will be saving them inside an array, which can be achieved like this:

```
$Names = array();
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $Names[$i] = $row['Name'];
    $i++;
}
```

Now you can retrieve your data this way:

```
echo $Names[0]; // Will output the first name saved.
```

Comment: you forgot to increment `$i` or it was not necessary?

Comment: @user2936213, Yup forgot.

Comment: Do you really need the $i ? Why don't you do: `$Names[] = blahblah;` ?

Comment: @AshrafSamhouri, `$Names[]` can act different in cases if we accidentally saved data to it before, but if we weren't like in my example then it equals to `$i`. No harm no foul.

Comment: If we have saved data to it before, it will get corrupted and one should expect wrong results somewhere in the program. New array should be created in this case and `[]` would always work!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to really persist the results, store them in an array:

```
<?php
        $data = array();
        // Note that I've changed "mysql_fetch_array" to "mysql_fetch_assoc" to decrease the number of saved data.
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $data[] = $row['Name'];
        }

        /* Now you can use the data wherever you want, like: $data[0]['Name'] for first name, $data[1]['Name'] for second name and so on */

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating so many new variables, why not create an array?

```
<?php
        $i=1;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $Names[$i]= $row['Name'];
            $i++;
        }
?>
```

You can then use the array in your code

```
echo $Names[1]; // 1 or 2 or 3 etc
```

For multiple attributes you can use a multidimensional array

```
        $i=1;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $Data[$i]["Name"]= $row['Name'];
            $Data[$i]["Phone"]= $row['Phone'];
            $i++;
        }
```

You can then use the array in your code

```
echo $Data[1]["Name"]; // 1 or 2 or 3 etc
```

Answer (score 1):

To strictly answer KOL's question:

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    $numbers = array('One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        if($i++ > count($numbers) {
            throw new NotMoreNumbersSupportedException();
        }
        $varname = 'Name' . $numbers[$i++];
        $$varname = $row['Name'];
    }
    var_dump($NameOne, $NameTwo, $NameThree, $NameFour, $NameFive); //etc
?>
```

Now shoot me.

Comment: Thanks for the strict answer but I used the array answer from above - better to learn the best practice way of doing things when trying learn new language :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can directly place html inside your `while` loop

   ```
   <?php
           while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
           {
               ?>
               <div><?php echo  $row['Name']; ?> </div>
               <div><?php echo  $row['PhoneNo']; ?> </div>
           <?php }
   ?>
   ```
2. You can add the details to another array

   ```
   <?php
           $names = array();
           $phnos = array();
           while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
           {
                $names[] = $row['Name'];  //$names[0] , $names[1] etc..
                $phnos[] = $row['PhoneNo']; //$phnos[0] , $phnos[1] etc..
           }
   ?>
   ```